# Runtime std::conditional

Tags: c++, polymorphism, dynamic-cast

I have polymorphic classes `Base`, `Derived1` and `Derived2`.

I want to make

`bool b = typeid(*base) == typeid(Derived1);`

`dynamic_cast<typename std::conditional<b, Derived1*, Derived2*>::type>(base)`

My compiler says that `b` is not a compile time expression (and I understand what this means). Is there a way to solve the problem?

Comment: What is `base`?

Comment: What do you want the type of that expression to be?

Comment: `if (b) .. else ....` instead of `std::conditional`.

Comment: The compiler can't make compile-time decisions based on information only available in runtime

Comment: @TedLyngmo actually they want to use a compile time facility to make a runtime decision. `std::conditional` is just the wrong tool here

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes it was the `std::conditional` I reacted on. Your `if (b) ... else ...` is the correct answer - or avoid it by using runtime polymorphism as BoP suggests below.

Comment: A common solution is to have a virtual function in Base, which the derived classes then implements differently. Perhaps you don't *need* to know the exact type?

Comment: I am curious how you ended up in using `std::conditional`.

Comment: Guys, I'm asking for std::conditional runtime equivalent, not for if-else or virtual creator :(

Comment: It isn't clear what this phrase "std::conditional runtime equivalent" should ever mean. Do you want a function with a return type that depends on some run time value? This is called "dependent type" (google it up), C++ doesn't have those.

Comment: the "std::conditional runtime equivalent" *is* if-else. It is unclear why you are looking for something else. C++ has not invtented something new because if-else is just fine. If you think it is not you need to say why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need `std::conditional` here. As you are making a dynamic cast, this cast happens at runtime anyhow, so theres no point in trying to push it into compile time. Just remove `std::conditional` and the problem is gone:

```
if (b) 
   dynamic_cast<Derived1*>(base)
else 
   dynamic_cast<Derived2*>(base)
```

Note that this code is as pseudo as yours and that chances are high that you do not need a cast in the first place. Maybe you do, but without context I guess that you rather need a virtual function.

Moreover, `bool b = typeid(*base) == typeid(Derived1);` looks like you want to cast to `Derived1*` only when the cast would suceed. However, `dynamic_cast` does already tell you when a cast cannot be made by returning a `nullptr`.

---

If you are looking for a way to "hide" the cast in a function, this isnt going to work. If you write a `base* my_cast(auto* x)` as you mention in a comment, it will always return a `base*` no matter what you cast inside the function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct base { 
    virtual ~base() {}
    void hello() { std::cout << "base\n";} // not virtual
};

struct derived : base {
    void hello() { std::cout << "derived\n";}
};

base* foo(auto* b) {
    auto d = dynamic_cast<derived*>(b);  // cast to derived  
    d->hello();
    return d;                            // and return
}

int main() {
    base b;
    auto x = foo(&b);
    std::cout << std::is_same<base*,decltype(x)>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << std::is_same<derived*,decltype(x)>::value << "\n";
    x->hello();
}
```

[Output is](https://godbolt.org/z/5jM5dexGf):

```
derived
1
0
base
```

Comment: Im trying to avoid if - else in this case because I belive there is a better way to do it. Like, we are in c++, is there nothing better than if - else? So I'm asking for std::conditional runtime equivalent

Comment: @FlufflePuff why do you think `if -else` is not good enough? If you explain what you think is bad about it perhaps we can find something better, but I see nothing wrong with it.

Comment: I'm coding a serializer for graphics engine. I have `WorldEngineObject` (base pure virtual class, WEO for short), `skybox` and `dimensional` which are derived from WEO. So I want to write (pseudo code): `void s(dimensional* d);` `void s(skybox* s);` `void serialize(vector<WEO*> * obj) { foreach(o in obj) s(dynamic_cast< "is actual type skybox?", "if yes, cast to skybox" "else cast to dimensional">(o)); }` then it chooses one of overloaded function. And I want to avoid if-else because I believe that there's a better way to do it

Comment: @FlufflePuff what exactly do you mean with "better" ?

Comment: More elegant, more genius

Comment: `if (b) ... else ... ` is very elegant imho. The guy who invented `if/else` must be a genius. Serisouly, I still have no clue what you are looking for. Aiming to write clever code usually ends in code that nobody wants to read. `if/else` is simple, it does the job, so whats wrong?

Comment: I've found a perfect solution. `f( get_type(obj) )` and `auto* get_type(auto* obj) { if(...) return "cast to skybox"; else return "cast to dimensional" ; }` this calmed me down

Comment: @FlufflePuff this doesnt work like you want it to work. `auto` will not magically adjust to the right type depending on the runtime condition

Comment: That's a pseudo code, so `auto` is a good way to not to complicate it (imho)

Comment: @FlufflePuff ... but, then you're actually just doing what's suggested in this answer really? When you've done the cast to `skybox` or `dimensional` then what do you return from the function?

Comment: @FlufflePuff but there is no return type you can replace `auto` with that would make the function return the right type depending on the condition, a function can have only one return type determined at compile time

Comment: If the function return type is Base* we can initialize it with Derived*   which is gonna be the actual type of value (we all remember about abstract factories). so that's what I do instead of `auto`

Comment: @FlufflPuff so you cast inside the function either to `Derived1*` or to `Derived2*` and then upon returning from the function there is implicit conversion to `Base*`. If this is what you want, then I am completely lost, such function is useless

Comment: This function is the way to hide If-else, that's something I was looking for

Comment: @FlufflePuff its not just hiding the if-else, but returning `Base*` makes the cast inside the function pointless. No matter what you cast, the function will always return a pointer to `Base` https://godbolt.org/z/sPPe5YqGq

Comment: @FlufflePuff Could it be that you wanted to invent runtime polymorphism in C++ and found out that it's already a core feature?